# Jade: how does one assign the 'checked' attribute to dynamically generated radio button inputs?

Tags: dynamic, radio-button, pug

I'm using Jade templates in an edit view where I edit a user's details, and a dynamically generated radio button like so (comes from my mongodb):

```
li Role:
      br
      label Subscriber
      input(type="radio", name="user[role]", val="subscriber")
      br
      label Admin
      input(type="radio", name="user[role]", val="admin")
      br
      label Super Admin
      input(type="radio", name="user[role]", val="superadmin")
```

How do I set one to checked dynamically?

So if in my db, my role is `subscriber` , how do I check for that? "Normally", I would do a `if(user.role == 'subscriber'){'checked'}` and so on for all of the different values.

Where/how does that logic go into this bit of Jade?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`input(type ='radio', name=user[role], checked)`

**To dynamically check, see examples below:**

```
input(type ='radio', name=user[role], checked=true)   
input(type ='radio', name=user[role], checked=false)   
input(type ='radio', name=user[role], checked=role=='user')
```